# How to save streaming data using Akka Persistence

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-persistence

I use StreamRefs to establish streaming connections between actors in the cluster. Currently, in the writing node, I save incoming messages to the log file manually, but I wonder is it possible to replace it with persistent `Sink` for writing and persistent `Source` for reading on actor startup 
 from the Akka Persistence journal. I've been thinking of replacing the log file sink with Persistent actor's `persist { evt => ... }`, but since it executes asynchronously I'll lose the backpressure. So is it possible to write streaming data with backpressure into Akka Persistence journal and read this data in a streaming manner on actor recover?

Current implementation:

```
object Writer {
  case class WriteSinkRequest(userId: String) 
  case class WriteSinkReady(userId: String, sinkRef: SinkRef[ByteString])
  case class ReadSourceRequest(userId: String)
  case class ReadSourceReady(userId: String, sourceRef: SourceRef[ByteString])
}

class Writer extends Actor {

    // code omitted

    val logsDir = "logs"

    val path = Files.createDirectories(FileSystems.getDefault.getPath(logsDir))

    def logFile(id: String) = {
        path.resolve(id)
    }

    def logFileSink(logId: String): Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.toPath(logFile(logId), Set(CREATE, WRITE, APPEND))
    def logFileSource(logId: String): Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(logFile(logId))

    override def receive: Receive = {
        case WriteSinkRequest(userId) => 
            // obtain the source you want to offer:
            val sink = logFileSink(userId)
            // materialize the SinkRef (the remote is like a source of data for us):
            val ref: Future[SinkRef[ByteString]] = StreamRefs.sinkRef[ByteString]().to(sink).run()
            // wrap the SinkRef in some domain message, such that the sender knows what source it is
            val reply: Future[WriteSinkReady] = ref.map(WriteSinkReady(userId, _))
            // reply to sender
            reply.pipeTo(sender())

        case ReadSourceRequest(userId) =>
            val source = logFileSource(userId)
            val ref: Future[SourceRef[ByteString]] = source.runWith(StreamRefs.sourceRef())
            val reply: Future[ReadSourceReady] = ref.map(ReadSourceReady(userId, _))
            reply pipeTo sender()

    }
}
```

P.S. Is it possible to create not a "save-to-journal" sink, but flow:
`incoming data to write ~> save to persistence journal ~> data that was written`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea for streaming data to a persistent actor in a backpressured fashion is to use [`Sink.actorRefWithAck`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-integrations.html#sink-actorrefwithack): have the actor send an acknowledgement message when it has persisted a message. This would look something like the following:

```
// ...
case class WriteSinkReady(userId: String, sinkRef: SinkRef[MyMsg])    
// ...

def receive = {
  case WriteSinkRequest(userId) =>
    val persistentActor: ActorRef = ??? // a persistent actor that handles MyMsg messages
                                        // as well as the messages used in persistentSink

    val persistentSink: Sink[MyMsg, NotUsed] = Sink.actorRefWithAck[MyMsg](
      persistentActor,
      /* additional parameters: see the docs */
    )

    val ref: Future[SinkRef[MyMsg]] = StreamRefs.sinkRef[MyMsg]().to(persistentSink).run()
    val reply: Future[WriteSinkReady] = ref.map(WriteSinkReady(userId, _))
    reply.pipeTo(sender())

  case ReadSourceRequest(userId) =>
    // ...
}
```

The above example uses a custom case class named `MyMsg` instead of `ByteString`.

In the sender, assuming it's an actor:

```
def receive = {
  case WriteSinkReady(userId, sinkRef) =>
    source.runWith(sinkRef) // source is a Source[MyMsg, _]

  // ...
}
```

The materialized stream in the sender will send the messages to the persistent actor.